# Why doesn't getchar() wait for me to press enter after scanf()?

Tags: c, getchar

I am learning C and I'm using "getchar()" to stop the command windows so I can see the exercises am doing but it just doesn't work. heres a sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int value;
    printf("1. option 1.\n2. option 2.\n3. option 3.\n4. Exit\n\nMake an option: ");
    scanf("%d", &value);
    switch (value)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("you selected the option 1.");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("you selected the option 2.");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("you selected the option 3.");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("goodbye");
            break;
        default:
            printf("thats not an option");
            break;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

> 1. option 1.
> 2. option 2.
> 3. option 3.
> 4. Exit.
>
> Make an option: 1
>
> you selected the option 1.
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.453 s
>
> Press any key to continue.

Why doesn't it wait for the input of "getchar()"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384073/problem-with-flushing-input-stream-c/1384089.

Answer (score 25):

Your scanf only ate the number but not the trailing newline. Putting a newline or white space after the %d will then give you the opposite problem, reading too far.

This is why people don't like scanf.

I would suggest reading an actual line (use `fgets(3)`) and then using `sscanf()` to scan the string.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, do *not* use fflush() to clear an input stream; the behavior is undefined:

> 7.19.5.2.2 If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
>     operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>     to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
>     undefined.

The problem is that the trailing newline is not being consumed by the "%d" conversion specifier, so it's being picked up immediately by the `getchar()`.  There's no one best way to deal with this, but generally the approach is to read the whole line as text (using either `fgets()` or `scanf()` with a sized "%s" conversion specifier), which will consume the newline, then convert to the target data type using `sscanf()` or `strtol()` or `strtod()`.

Comment: Can u please give us a example? I wasnt able to implement this in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Can getchar be getting your carriage return that you enter after the 1?

Comment: Yes, getchar() is getting the newline that terminates the input, and therefore it does not wait long since the data is already in its buffers.

Comment: Heck if that was wrong.  I'm liking the fflush answer and trying it out.

Comment: But it's undefined behavior, potentially nonportable, and particularly not recommended for a homework-style learning experience. Follow the published and standardized API! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The getchar() is reading the \n from the keyboard in scanf - see [here](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-60.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

I think you input a enter after inputting "1". It will be accepted by the `getchar()`.So you can solve the problem simply by add an additional `getchar()` after the original one(just before the `return 0;`).

** I tested this and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

you are getting a carriage return, the way i would get around it, define a char and just have it scan the carriage return,

`char ch;`
(before your getch() enter the following)
`scanf("%c",&ch);
getchar();`

should work this way, not the most efficient way to do this but works for me.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already scanf leaves \n behind after reading user input.

**Soultion:** add getchar() straight after scanf.

That compensates scanf deficiency.

i.e.

```
int value; 
printf("1. option 1.\n2. option 2.\n3. option 3.\n4. Exit\n\nMake an option: "); 
scanf("%d", &value);
getchar();
switch (value)
```

Answer (score 0):

while reading other answers it just came to me that you can use `scanf("%d\n",&n);`
instead of `scanf("%d",&n);` to remove new line from buffer. I haven't checked this out though.

Hope it works :D

Comment: I think this won't work for recursive functions but should work fine for loops. "You can't please everyone"

Comment: This won't work as expected.  Because of the `\n` in the format string, `scanf` won't return until you enter a non-whitespace character *after* entering any digits.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<conio.h>
void main() 
{ 
    int value; 
    printf("1. option 1.\n2. option 2.\n3. option 3.\n4. Exit\n\nMake an option: "); 
    scanf("%d", &value); 
    switch (value) 
    { 
        case 1: 
            printf("you selected the option 1."); 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            printf("you selected the option 2."); 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            printf("you selected the option 3."); 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            printf("goodbye"); 
            break; 
        default: 
            printf("thats not an option"); 
            break; 
    } 
    getch(); 
}
```

Comment: So, your answer is to use `getch` instead? Could you make that more clear (if it is indeed the case)?

Answer (score -10):

in order for your program to work, you should "flush" your input stream before calling getchar() with a call to fflush(stdin). What this does is, when you type in you keyboard a number and then the return key, the input buffer gets both characters, for example '1' and '\n', and your call to scanf gets only '1' so the '\n' remains in the input buffer. When you call getchar, you are "gettin" that remaining '\n'. Flushing the input discards all the buffer.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is _undefined behavior_.  Don't do it.

Comment: then how i should do it? 
am really new to this, am coming from python as my first programming language so everything about memory management is Chinese to me..

Comment: wow .. I didn't know .. just made some research and found this explanation http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-57.html

Comment: See my answer or the accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384073/problem-with-flushing-input-stream-c/1384089.  It comes down to a) using `fgets` to read the entire line then parse it using `sscanf` or b) putting in a second `getchar` to "eat" the newline.

Comment: Sorry to be harsh about `fflush(stdin)`, but it's one of those things that really seems like it should work until it causes a nasty bug that you can't track down.

Comment: I've deleted my answer since this is such a **BAD** idea :)