# Comparing char in a while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

As long as the input is not x, the loop will continue to ask for the input and it prints out either A or B.

```
int main (void){

    char input;

    while( input != 'x'){

        printf("Enter Input:");

        scanf("%c", &input);

        if (input == 'a'){

            printf("A \n");
        }

        else{

            printf("B\n");
        }

   }

    return (0);
}
```

The problem is that everytime after i entered the input,  it prints the output and it also prints out "Enter Input:B" in a new line no matter i entered a or b or anything else as input. Can anyone tell me how can i solve this problem, Thanks!

Here is what happened:

> Enter Input:a
>
> A
>
> Enter Input:B    /*after the output it always prints this line, how
>   can i get rid of it??*/
>
> Enter Input:a
>
> A
>
> Enter Input:B
>
> Enter Input:b
>
> B
>
> Enter Input:B
>
> Enter Input:b

Answer (score 4):

In order to ignore newlines, the `scanf` should likely be:

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
       ^
```

Also you probably want to flush stdout right after that `printf`:

```
printf("Enter Input:");
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to eat a `newline` char:

```
scanf("%c", &input);
  while((ch=getchar())!='\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the newline character is read from input.

You can refer to this one too : [Why doesn't getchar() wait for me to press enter after scanf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391548/why-doesnt-getchar-wait-for-me-to-press-enter)