# i have to use getchar(); twice to end program

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn't getchar() wait for me to press enter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391548/why-doesnt-getchar-wait-for-me-to-press-enter)

I continue to learn C, and at this stage I have something that is not clear to me.
When I write a program, that has several `printf();`, at the end, where I ask a user to press Enter key to finish the program, I have to write `getchar();` twice, because when I write it once it does not work. I use `getchar();` only at the end of the program, nowhere else.

I work on Ubuntu. I write in C.

here is my latest work:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int m,n,r,k,q,l;
printf("This program will help you to find GCD & LCM of 2 non-negative integers\n");
printf("Now, you'll be asked to enter your integers, press Enter to continue");
getchar();
printf("Enter first integer:");
scanf("%i", &m);
printf("Enter second integer:");
scanf("%i", &n);
while(m<0 || n<0)
{
printf("The integers cannot be negative! You'll be asked to enter integers again.\n");
printf("Enter first integer:");
scanf("%i", &m);
printf("Enter second integer:");
scanf("%i", &n);
}
while(m==0 && n==0)
{
printf("Both of the integers cannot be zero at the same time! You'll be asked to enter integers again.\n");
printf("Enter first integer:");
scanf("%i", &m);
printf("Enter second integer:");
scanf("%i", &n);
}
if(n>m)
{
int b;
b=n;
n=m;
m=b;
}
r=m%n;
if(r==0)
{
printf("The GCD of these integers is %i\n", n);
printf("The LCM of these integers is %i\n", m);
printf("Press Enter to finish");
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
k=n%r;
while(k>0)
{
r=k;
k=q;
}
l=(m*n)/r;
printf("The GCD of these integers is %i\n", r);
printf("The LCM of these integers is %i\n", l);
printf("Press Enter to finish");
getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Also, I have another question" -- then have it in *another question*.

Comment: `scanf` leaves the ENTER waiting in the buffer. The first `getchar` "eats" that ENTER; the second `getchar` waits for input.

Comment: @H2CO3, if you've got an answer - so please, answer.

Comment: @pmg, thanks. I understood. I found that fflush clears the buffer, but I did not find a way to creectly use it. can u help me?

Comment: @EmiLazE: try to use `fgets` (and `sscanf`) instead of `scanf`. `fgets` "eats" all of the input up to and including the ENTER. `scanf` wasn't designed for dealing with input from humans.

Comment: @pmg, will try it. 
so I have to write at the end something like this?
fgets();

Comment: No. Replace your `scanf("%d", ...)` calls with the pair `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); sscanf(buffer, "%d", ...);`. Don't forget to define buffer before using it, for example: `char buffer[1000];`

Comment: @EmiLazE No, you use `fgets` and `sscanf` _instead of_ `scanf`.

Comment: Oh! **don't use `fflush` on input streams**: that operation (`fflush` on input streams) is undefined in the C89 Standard (many C implementations today are still C89).

Comment: but one more thing - what is the difference in size of buffer?

Comment: `fgets` needs to know how much space it can use (to avoid buffer overflows). That's why it is passed the size of the buffer (it automatically takes into account the string terminator).

Comment: @pmg not only C89. It is UB in any C Standard (the latest Standard being C17 as of now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you need 2 `getchar()` is because

1. the last `scanf()` call left the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> waiting in the buffer
2. the 1st `getchar()` "ate" that <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
3. the 2nd `getchar()` waits for input.

---

To properly deal with user input, use `fgets()` and `sscanf()` instaed of the simpler `scanf()`. Define a buffer for these functions, for example

```
char buffer[1000];
```

and then replace your `scanf()` calls with the pair

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
```

---

In the future you might want to also check the return value of `sscanf()` to detect invalid inputs, like <kbd>foo42</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n) != 1) /* invalid input */;
```

---

Edit (using `strtol()` rather than `sscanf()` is even better -- thanks to @Scooter)

```
char buffer[1000];
char *err;
/* ... */
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); /* error checking ommited */
n = strtol(buffer, &err, 10);
/* error checking ommited */
/* ... */
```

Comment: atoi() and strtol() can also be used to get a C string into an int.

Comment: `atoi()` is not a good choice because there is no way to detect errors. **`strtol()` is even better than `sscanf()`**, thanks!

Comment: +1 for discouraging scanf(). C books should start using fgets()+sscanf() instead of scanf(). unbuffered IO is always dangerous