# Get text from user input using C

Tags: c

I am just learning C and making a basic "hello, NAME" program. I have got it working to read the user's input but it is output as numbers and not what they enter?

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[20];

    printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%d", &name);
    printf("Hi there, %d", name);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use %s instead of %d and use fgets not scanf. fgets reads input from a stream from string

Comment: You might want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: C programs are typically not referred to as "scripts", they are programs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You use the wrong format specifier `%d`- you should use `%s`. Better still use fgets - scanf is not buffer safe.

Go through the documentations it should not be that difficult:

[scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) and [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
    //scanf("%s", &name);  - deprecated
    fgets(name,20,stdin);
    printf("Hi there, %s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
The Name is Stackoverflow
```

Output:

```
Hello. What's your name?
Hi there, The Name is Stackov
```

Comment: Note that fgets() will also pick-up the newline character (\n) at the end of the input.  So an input of "Bob" is captured as "Bob\n".  If this is unacceptable, then the newline character has to be manually removed.  You'll need a line of code like:
name[ strlen( name)-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char name[20];

printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
scanf("%s", name);
printf("Hi there, %s", name);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2036031 check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391548/why-doesnt-getchar-wait-for-me-to-press-enter) I think thats why your programme close right after message.

Comment: You wouldn't address-of the array label, i.e. the `name` while `scanf`ing a string. OP better learns that correctly and does not get misinformed by these answers...

Answer (score 1):

When we take the input as a string from the user, `%s` is used. And the address is given where the `string` to be stored.

```
scanf("%s",name);
printf("%s",name);
```

hear name give you the `base address` of `array` **name**. The value of `name` and `&name` would be `equal` but there is very much difference between them. `name` gives the `base address` of `array` and if you will calculate `name+1` it will give you `next address` i.e. address of `name[1]` but if you perform `&name+1`, it will be `next address` to the `whole array`.

Answer (score -2):

change your code to:

```
int main()
{
    char name[20];

    printf("Hello. What's your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Hi there, %s", name);

    getchar();
    getch();                  //To wait until you press a key and then exit the application
    return 0;
}
```

This is because, %d is used for integer datatypes and %s and %c are used for string and character types

Comment: You wouldn't address-of the array label, i.e. the `name` while `scanf`ing a string. OP better learns that correctly and does not get misinformed by these answers...