# I don't understand why I can't get three inputs in c

Tags: c, scanf

A friend of mine is trying to learn c (on her own, with a book) and sometimes she asks for help.

She just showed me something I can't answer; I'm ashamed but I studied C in college and then moved to php. I'm really stuck so I would like to know why we can't get three inputs. Here's partial code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char x;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&num1);
    printf("Enter another number:\n");
    scanf("%d\n",&num2);
    printf("Choose an operation sign:\n");
    scanf("%c\n",&x);

...
```

Like this it asks for the first input two times, like this:

```
Enter a number:
1
2
Enter another number:
3
Choose an operation sign:
-
```

If I remove the `\n` it skips the last `scanf`.

Can you help me understand why?

Comment: Note that with the example input above, you get `num1 == 1`, `num2 == 2`, `x == '3'`.

Comment: if you remove the \n, the program doesn't skip the last scanf. instead, the \n which is still left behind in the buffer by scanf gets stored in variable x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read here: [scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer/5240807#5240807)

Solution:

```
int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char x;

    printf("Enter a number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter another number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("Choose an operation sign:\n");
    scanf("\n%c",&x); /* See the \n <---------------- */
}
```

An alternative:

```
char buf[2]; /* We need 2 characters for the null */
scanf("%1s", buf); /* We ask max 1 character (plus null given by scanf) */
char x = buf[0]; /* We take the first character */
```

As a small note, thanks to how `scanf` works, with both the solutions you can insert directly in the first "input" all the data and the various `scanf` will take their part. So you could insert `123 234 +` and it would be split in the three variables correctly.

Comment: See this question for another way to ensure all junk is flushed from stdin between reads:
[I am not able to flush stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin)

Comment: @Daniel In the end there isn't a "portable" solution. Even the C FAQ tells it and suggests an alternative http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Comment: @xanatos the C FAQ page you listed has a portable code snippet for clearing out the buffer :P

Comment: @Farhan Yes you are right but I was looking at it from another POV. In the end it's breaking the "standard" scanf working, where you can pre-set the next values (so if you had inputted `5 3` you would have "filled" the first two scanf and with `5 3 +` you have the whole reverse polish operation)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `scanf` does not remove the newline, and you can't flush `stdin`, so how about this:

```
int num1;
char nleater;
printf("Enter a number:\n");
scanf("%d%c", &num1, &nleater);
```

or indeed this:

```
printf("Enter number sign number: ");
scanf("%d %c %d",&num1,&x,&num2);
printf("%d %c %d", num1, x, num2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use `fflush`, but it depends on the library implementation (stdio). 
The C reference for it can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fflush/).

I'll test this a bit later on and update my post and say whether it worked.

Comment: invoking fflush on inputstream leads to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Depends on compiler, VC empties the input stream. Of course, this is highly non-portable.

Comment: Not on the compiler, but the actual library implementation (as it's stated in the reference). This means that the behavior can change when the library is updated. But for learning purposes you could use that as it's not a production environment where you may have a need for long term support or portability.