# Skips over my fgets

Tags: c

I am programming in C. For some reason is just skips over my fgets and runs the code afterwards and I don't know why.

```
char content[256];
printf("What do you want it to say?\n");
fgets(content, 256, stdin);
```

Comment: The problem is in the code before this code.

Comment: Probably telling you not to use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried flushing stdin?  You may have a newline char caught in it that is causing your fgets to return instantly.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin) references a good way to flush the stdin

Comment: Can you explain it to me like I was a 15 year old and this is his first low-level language

Comment: Be aware that `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior (as the answers to the linked question explain).

Answer (score 1):

Recall that I/O can be buffered.  If there is anything waiting in the input buffer when your function is called, it will be read in.  In the event that the first character in the buffer is a `'\n'`, the function will return immediately and appear to gather no input.  Ensure that there is nothing in the input buffer before calling `fgets()`.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense, but how do I do that?

Comment: As far as clearing out the input buffer goes, there is sample code in [the C FAQs](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html) that could be useful.  When you encounter problems with stray characters in the input buffer, it's usually a hint that there's something wrong in the I/O code that came *before* this.

Comment: I used the example code, and it works. But for some reason, when it appends the string to a file it adds two enters before it. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Actually, just one enter before and one after

Comment: @TannerEllis- There's no way to tell based only on your description.  You'd need to post [enough code to demonstrate the problem](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

```
char content[256];
printf("What do you want it to say?\n");
while ( getchar() != '\n');
fgets(content, 256, stdin);
```

OR did you try this...

```
 char content[256];
 printf("What do you want it to say?\n");
 fgets(content, 256, stdin);
```