# C fgets. I use it in a dowhile but the first time it is used it's like it doesn't exist

Tags: c, fgets

I got a question about fgets in C programming.

I am using  fgets() function  in my code(example of input: A4 N) inside a do-while.
(so that the input will be correct) But for some reason the first time it's like fgets() doesn't exist.

To help you understand me, this is what appears after running it.I also tried to use scanf()  but failed..

```
Example of positioning: G3 E
Aircraft carrier (5 places), Give location and direction: 
1
Aircraft carrier (5 places), Give location and direction:
```

My Code is:

```
void arrayFill(char **array, int r, int c, int player)
{
char position[10];
printf("\n%s", "Example of positioning: G3 E");
do
{
    printf("\n%s", "Aircraft carrier (5 places), Give location and direction: ");
    fgets(position, 10, stdin);
    printf("\n%s", "1");
}while(validPosition(array, r, c, position, 5) == 2);
```

Comment: The first `fgets` might be eating up an empty line. Try `printf("'%s'\n", position);` right after the `fgets`.

Comment: Are you using `scanf()` to read field oriented input beforehand, by chance?

Comment: i don't understand what field oriented means but yes in my program i used some scanf before this part of the code.

Comment: iarsmans indeed there is an empty line...but why is that?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common pitfall of mixing field-oriented input (what `scanf()` uses) and line oriented input. Field oriented input doesn't care much about line feeds, and when you use something like

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

and you enter "42\n" the "\n" is actually left over on `stdin`. You don't notice it with subsequent `scanf()` calls, as (with few exceptions) `scanf()` will ignore leading whitespace.

When you call `fgets()` after your `scanf()` call, there is a `'\n'` left on `stdin`, and `fgets()` is happy to accept this "empty line" for you.  It's easy enough to write code to ignore the remainder of a line after your `scanf()` completes:

```
int ch;
/* call to scanf() */
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) { /* do nothing */ }
```

After doing this, there won't be any left over line feeds.

Comment: that was actually a really nice explanation. thank you :) i will try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to '\n' character. There is another topic it could help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033477/why-is-the-first-string-ignored-when-reading-with-fgets-from-stdin?rq=1).