# C while loop skipping over input

Tags: c, input, while-loop

This is a homework issue.  I have a C program that's reading in input.  It takes a number of people the user wants to record, designated here by the variable choice, and then records their first and last names and age into respective arrays.  I have a while loop to get input from the user, but the first cycle through the while loop completely skips getting the first piece of input.  After the first cycle through, though, it does correctly record the user's input.  I was wondering what I might be doing wrong.  Here is my while loop:

```
char firstName[choice][20];
char lastName[choice][20];
int age[choice][3];
while(i < choice + 1)
{
  fputs("Enter the first name of the person  ", stdout);
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets(firstName[i], sizeof firstName[i], stdin);

  fputs("Enter the last name of the person  ", stdout);
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets(lastName[i], sizeof lastName[i], stdin);

  fputs("Enter the age of the person  ", stdout);
  fflush(stdout);
  fgets(age[i], sizeof age[i], stdin);

  i++;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: age is int?  don't use fgets

Comment: Hoping that you're `i` and `choice` declarations are fine, the code works in `gcc` here. I don't seem to replicate your problem on my computer. Also, don't use `fgets()` for `int`.

Comment: i is initiallized to 0 and choice is taken as input from the user.  this is what I have for those: int choice;
int i = 0;
      fputs("How many people would you like to add? ", stdout);
      scanf(" %d", &choice);
      fflush(stdout);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the first string ignored when reading with fgets from stdin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033477/why-is-the-first-string-ignored-when-reading-with-fgets-from-stdin)

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code in this way

```
i = 0;
while(i < choice)
```

The while should stop at the `choice - 1` and not at `choice` because the array indices in C strat from `0`.

```
0,1,2,...,(choice-1) //==> the total is (choice) indices
```

Comment: OP's code reads all the loops except the first. He may have declared `choice` in a certain way. His question is on why the first iteration seems to skip over.