# Why this program always shows U at the end

Tags: c

I have created following C code for encrypt words.(caesar cipher) when I run this it prints U at the end always.if you run this you will see it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x;
    char en[100];

    fgets(en,100,stdin);
    for(x=0;x<100;x++){
        if(en[x]=='\0'){
            break;
        }
        en[x]=((en[x]-71-3)%26)+97;
    }
    printf("%s\n",en);
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find out.

Answer (score 6):

`fgets` places a '\n' character before the '\0' at the end of the buffer. So if you don't want to encrypt it, loop until the condition below is satisfied:

```
if (en[x] == '\0' || en[x] == '\n') break;
```

To be rigorous, the actual reason why you are getting a `U` is due to the fact that `\n` has ASCII code 10. Thus, `(10-74)%26 + 97 = 85`, which is the ASCII code for `U`.

Comment: Loop while `x<99` won't help if the string is shorter than that.

Comment: ohhhhh thank you very much.i have been suffering from this problem for 6 hours.i have a another qs.i thought fgets places '\0' at the end like scanf.why is that wrong?

Comment: Actually fgets terminates the buffer with \n\0. See http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Answer (score 0):

```
if (en[x] == '\0' || en[x] == '\n') break;
```

The above condition should solve your problem.
some reading for the \0 and \n is given in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711449/what-does-the-0-symbol-mean-in-a-c-string)

he is a output of the "trail" run which give more insight on a step by step way

`trial`

```
*rial
rial
q(ial
qial
qoal
qoal
qofl
qofl
qofx"
qofx
qofxi?
qofxi?
qofxiU
```

Comment: I thought fgets places '\0' at the end like scanf.why is that wrong?

Comment: `fgets` puts the values in the buffer until the you press enter
for example: if you type in `trial` for `stdin`
you press enter which is also returned during `fgets()`
but `scanf()` doesn't do that. you might get more idea from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033477/why-is-the-first-string-ignored-when-reading-with-fgets-from-stdin?rq=1) as well