# Modulus in language C

Tags: c, modulus

I'm having some trouble with this line of code: (sorry it is in danish)

```
 case 1 :
     system("cls");
       printf("K maa kun have en veardi mellem 1 og 20\nIndtast k:");
        scanf("%d", &k1);
  while(!(k1>=1 && k1 <=20))//Starten på fejlsikret tilstand
    {
     printf("K er for hoej eller har en forkert veardi.\nProev igen:  ");
     fflush(stdin);
     scanf("%d", &k1);
    }//slutning på fejlsikret tilstand

 system("cls");
 printf("X maa kun have en veardi mellem 1 og 20\nIndtast din modstanders tal: ");
 scanf("%d", &x1);
while(!(x1<21))//Starten på fejlsikret tilstand
 {
 printf("X er for høj.");
 scanf("%d", &x1);
 }//slutning på fejlsikret tilstand

            newmove=(21-x1)%(k1+1)+x1;
            printf("Du skal sige = %d", newmove);
            printf("\n\n\nTryk 1 og afslut med Enter for at komme tilbage til start");
            scanf("%d", &m);
            continue;
```

But it seems that the modulus part is calculating wrong. eks: 
If I put in the numbers: x1 = 12 and k1 = 12, it gives me 20. But it should be 17. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't flush `stdin`...

Comment: may be he wants to flush stdout

Comment: how do you figure that it should be 17? (21-12) % (12+1) + 12 doesn't seem to add up to 17.

Comment: Where is initialization and assignment for k1 ?

Comment: Nope.. I want to clear any number in the previous variables..

Comment: `(21 - 12) % (12 + 1) + 12` doesn't add up to `20` either…

Comment: @Lasse - It's UB. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin)

Comment: I have testet it on this site: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2812-20%29mod%2812%2B1%29%2B12

Comment: @Lasse Cool. But those are completely different numbers than you have in your code and your description of the problem.

Comment: yea.. just figured out.. I'm so sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the newmove should be `21`

```
newmove=(21-x1) % (k1 + 1) + x1;
        (21-12) % (12 + 1) + 12
        (  9    %    13  ) + 12
                9          + 12
         21
```

Answer (score 0):

newmove=(21-x1)%(k1+1)+x1;

So if x1=12 and k1=12

```
newmove=(21-12)%(12+1)+12;
newmove=9%13+12;
newmove=9+12
newmove=21
```

Why should it be 17 ?

Comment: OH MY GOD.. So sorry!! waste of your time!! You are completly right.. i was messing out on the code.. sry..

Comment: Don't worry, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect your result to be 21. Substituting x1=12 and k1=12 into this expression:

```
(21-x1)%(k1+1)+x1
```

gives:

```
(21-12)%(12+1)+12 = (9)%(13)+12 = 9 + 12 = 21
```