# scanf not recognises %59[^\n]

Tags: c, string, struct, scanf

Hello all what i am trying to do is to `scanf` a string to 2 struct variables but when running the code it simply passes though the `scanf` (both of them) and goes to the `printf`.

My code is the following:

```
struct s_Especialidade{
    char nome[60];
    char descricao[60];
    struct s_Especialidade *proximo;
};

typedef struct s_Especialidade Especialidade;
typedef Especialidade *PESPECIALIDADE; 

void novaEspecialidade()
{
    PESPECIALIDADE novo = malloc(sizeof(Especialidade) );
    int opcao=0;
    printf("\nNome: ");
    scanf("%59[^\n]\n", (novo->nome));
    printf("\nDescricao: ");
    scanf("%59[^\n]\n", (novo->descricao));
    novo->proximo = NULL;
    printf("\n%s - %s",novo->nome, novo->descricao);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  You can always edit your own question; I've transplanted the extra information into the question for you this time, but you could have done it too.  Since you don't check the return value from `scanf()`, you can't tell whether it is happy or not.  What was the read operation before this?  Did it make sure that the newline before was read?

Answer (score 4):

The trouble is that white space (including newlines) in `scanf()` format strings behaves peculiarly — it means an arbitrary sequence of white space characters.

When it prompts `Nome:`, you can type a name ('Alexander the Great') and a newline, but the `scanf()` keeps reading until it comes across another character that isn't white space.  So, you might type 'Conqueror of Asia', and then the prompt `Descricao:` will appear, and it will read until you type another character that isn't white space, and then it will terminate.

For example:

```
$ ./name-prompt
Nome: Alexander The Great 
Conqueror of Asia

Descricao: a

<<Alexander The Great>> - <<Conqueror of Asia>>
$
```

This is from the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct s_Especialidade{
    char nome[60];
    char descricao[60];
    struct s_Especialidade *proximo;
};

typedef struct s_Especialidade Especialidade;
typedef Especialidade *PESPECIALIDADE; 

static
void novaEspecialidade(void)
{
  PESPECIALIDADE novo = malloc(sizeof(Especialidade) );
  printf("\nNome: ");
  if (scanf("%59[^\n]\n", (novo->nome)) != 1)
      printf("Oh, bother!\n");
  printf("\nDescricao: ");
  if (scanf("%59[^\n]\n", (novo->descricao)) != 1)
      printf("Oh, bother!\n");
  novo->proximo = NULL;
  printf("\n<<%s>> - <<%s>>\n", novo->nome, novo->descricao);
  free(novo);
}

int main(void)
{
  novaEspecialidade();
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the `printf()` output ends with a newline; that's generally a good idea.

To work around this, modify the `scanf()` format to:

```
"%59[^\n]"
```

After the `scanf()`, do the equivalent of:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;
```

Package it into a function — maybe `gobble()` or `read_to_newline()`.

Or use `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` to parse it; that often works better.

Comment: +1 for "use `fgets()` to read the line and `sscanf()` to parse it"

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read 60 characters and indicating that by 59 in the `scanf` statement?  Then, your `scanf` is wrong.  Change it to: `scanf ( "%s", novo->nome );` and it should work.  Same with the other `scanf`.

Comment: Thx for your response but i already tried that, and the resulte was if i input a name for example mine "Ricardo Sacramento" the space in the middle will be the end of the first scanf and then in my result printf will be ricardo - sacramento and the objective is to appear a name "ricardo Sacramento"- "description" for example. I want the scanf to read until a \n appear or until 59 characters.

Comment: Then, you may want to change it to `gets` or `fgets`.  That will allow you to read till the newline.  You can use `fgets ( novo->nome, sizeof ( novo->nome ), stdin );` and you should be good but may have to replace the tailing newline character by a `NULL`.

Comment: To remove the newline character as a result of `fgets`, add the following statement: `novo->nome[strlen(novo->nome)-1] = NULL;`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a complete example, reading two strings from stdin, then using sscanf to remove the trailing newline and printing them:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct {
    char first[60];
    char second[60];
} store;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    char buffer[60];

    printf("write something: ");
    fgets(buffer, 60, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%s", store.first);

    printf("write something else: ");
    fgets(buffer, 60, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%s", store.second);

    printf("you wrote: %s then %s\n", store.first, store.second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to read 'at most 59 characters' precisely; he wants to read at most 59 non-newline characters followed by a newline (not that he'll ever be able to tell whether the newline was actually matched).

Comment: You're right, my answer was stupid... rewrote it to use fgets

Comment: I want to be able to read a string with a space in between for the max of 59 characters.

Comment: well... fgets reads one line, so it stops at the first newline, and the size parameter force it to stop at 60 characters.

Comment: I did try it and what happens is when i compile it with "fgets(novo->nome,59,stdin" and "fgets(novo->descricao,59,stdin);" the output is: nome:                                                                    descricao: and then i start writing and i should be wrinting in the middle

Comment: I tried you example and still when compiling does not let me introduce the name it passes always though it right to the description its like the first fgets is not there

Comment: Do you mean that running my example as a "standalone" program does not works? Or do you mean it doesn't works when included in your program? If that's the second, are you using the input stream before? If so, you may have to flush the input stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin

Comment: I mean when included does not work it only stops for input in the description not in the name, and no its the first input stream

Comment: yeah... that's it then, try adding `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` before the first input (with c being a char)

Comment: i will try it but what does the line do? IT WORKED so many thanks to all guys rly. Just saved my life xD. but what its does the line?? thx

Comment: Your `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');` loop requires `c` to be an `int` for reliable operation.  If it isn't, you run into one of two problems, depending on whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned.  If plain `char` is signed, then a valid character (e.g 0xFF, often ÿ, y-umlaut, formally U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) matches EOF and prematurely terminates the input.  If plain `char` is unsigned, no value ever matches EOF, so the loop won't terminate on EOF.