# scanf reads previous line instead of getting new one

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int opt;
scanf("%d",&opt);
while(opt!=0)
{
    switch(opt)
    {
    case 1:func1();
        break;
    case 2:func2();
        break;
    case 3:return 0;
    }
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&opt);
}
```

I want to computer to get from user everytime different digit (1 or 2 or 3) and in every time the computer will run on seperate function. but when I press 2, func2 gets 3 ints and prints chars on the screen in a new line. the computer reads them instead of reading next input (1 or 2 or 3). how can I fix it?

**EDIT:** The problem rises only after specific inputs (I build a program converts bases).

*Input:*

```
2

10

26

1z2
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
ERROR
```

*INPUT:*

```
2

38762

10
```

*UNWANTED OUTPUT:*

```
201222
```

I'm not sure from where the computer scans the second num it uses to print the last unwanted output.

Comment: Sow your functions definitions.

Comment: Providing function definitions of `func1()` and `func2()` would be helpful to us to answer your question.

Comment: It's hard to tell without actually knowing what the functions do, if you replace them with dummy function, the code works, obviously.

Comment: your second scanf is supposed to block but it isn't because opt is not empty

Comment: @hhachem what do you mean? to remove the ampersand? in the function func2 it works great except for the case I edited in original post (and obviously func2 includes some scanfs).

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf` and take it into consideration. Read about it here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf

Answer (score 1):

your second scanf is supposed to block but it isn't because the input buffer is not empty after the first call! This is why it is always returning the previous value and looping infinitely.
Use a combination of `fgets` and `sscanf` instead.

Also check this : http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: I don't i'm allowed to do so. however what is the difference between scanf and fgets except security issues?

Comment: fgets reads input from stdin and stores it in an array. Then you can parse it using sscanf. scanf is really bad, because once you hit `enter` it won't read new inputs because it will always detect `enter`pressed in the buffer. Check the link in my answer it can explain why in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If your functions use `scanf()` inside them to ask for characters or you are using `fgets()` to read a while line, you might find that `scanf()` / `fgets()` does run without user input. This is because the newline character you entered at `scanf("%d",&opt);` is still there and is used as new input for the next `scanf()/fgets()`. You have to erase it by issuing

```
fflush (stdin);
```

Just prior to call `scanf()` or `fgets()`

Comment: `fflush (stdin);` is undefined behavior http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin

Comment: @StoryTeller Correct. Although he is right about clearing stdin, I would rather use `fgets` and insert an `\0` at the beginning of the buffer, so the next `fgets` call blocks. `sscanf` can then be used to parse the integer

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` has a documented behavior for both input and output streams, at least for Windows, according to the MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix It is extended by microsoft as explained in the example code. It is non-standard in C and therefore not portable. `fflush` can only be used on output streams as explained here: http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html

Comment: @Coargu Aliquis `char buffer[512]=""; fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);` this reads the input and stores it in buffer as a series of characters (aka string). You will have to use `sscanf` afterwards to get the integer since `scanf` does not allow you to specify from where you want to read. Also once you are done with the input you will have to delete it by `buffer[0]='\0';`
Haccks's solution should work by the way.

Answer (score 1):

you may need something like this..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int opt;

    do{
        printf("Enter the option\n");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        switch(opt){
            case 1: func1();
                    break;
            case 2: func2();
                    break;
            case 3: 
                    return 0;
        }

    }while(opt != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem that is pointed out by [hhachem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816731/hhachem) in comment that you are not exiting from your `while` loop.
You can solve this problem by doing (as you want to exit only after pressing 3):

```
 while(1)
{
    switch(1)
    {
        case 1:func1();
            break;
        case 2:func2();
            break;
        case 3: exit(0);
    }
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&opt);
}
```

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int opt;
    scanf("%d",&opt);
    while(1)
    {
        switch(opt)
        {
            case 1:printf("1");
                   break;
            case 2:printf("2");
                   break;
            case 3:exit(0);
         }

         printf("\n");
         scanf("%d",&opt);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See the [output](http://ideone.com/XC7OBl).

Comment: I want to exit it only after I press 3. I can exit from it, can't I?

Comment: returning `0` from `main` (which is curiously absent from the OP, but I assume this is the code inside it) will exit just fine.

Comment: @CoarguAliquis; Yes, you can. See the updated answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.

Comment: @haccks, I don't know what question you are answering, but your revised code sample still suffers the same problem as the OP and intoduces a new one a-la `switch(1)`. It doesn't matter how the OP exits, as long as it can't parse it's input correctly.

Comment: No i misread the code earlier. Check my answer below. The issue is scanf and the input buffer being populated by the first scanf call. So all following scanf calls do not read anymore because the input buffer has not been cleared.

Comment: @haccks I see. it runs on my system too. Nonetheless, I'm not a fan of `scanf`, there are far better options out there.

Comment: @hhachem; I am also not a big fan of it but OP wants to use this function in his program (as he stated in the comment in responce to your answer.

Comment: @haccks Oh yes I missed that.