# C programming simple issue .Asking two Inputs on same line

Tags: c

Hello i am beginner in programmin. I have simple issue. When i take user input. I was asked
Enter Your Age: 
then after entering age i was asked(problem is here: why it's executing two linesc)
"Enter c for city and v for village:  Enter 'h' for healthy and 'p' for poor health: "

and cursor comes after   health:

It should ask for "Enter c for city and v for village:"  first. I have tried alot. Please help me

```
int main(){
int age;
char sex;
char location;
char health;

printf("Enter Your Age: ");
scanf("%d",&age);
printf("Enter c for city and v for village: ");
scanf("%c", &location);
printf("Enter 'h' for healthy and 'p' for poor health: ");
scanf("%c", &health);
printf("Enter 'm' for male and 'f' for female: ");
scanf("%c", &sex);


if(age>=25 && age<=35){

  printf("hello ahmed ");
}
    else{
         printf("Sorry You Cannot Be Insured ");
}


getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: The correct solution depends on whether you are using C or C++. They are not the same language!

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ChristianHackl i am using simple c..please help

Comment: @user3370739: then please consider removing the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you enter your age, the 'enter' remains in the buffer and gets read into location.

```
printf("Enter Your Age: ");
scanf("%d",&age); 
printf("Enter c for city and v for village: ");
scanf("\n%c", &location); // add this line to ignore the newline character.
```

EDIT: `fflush()` removed because it seems it works only for output streams and not input. IMO Better is to first read the `newline` character and then the actual `location` character.

Comment: instead of using `getch()`, it's safer to use `fflush(stdin)`

Comment: @Abishek result is the same

Comment: @AbhisshekBansal Indeed the behaviour of fflush on input streams is not standardized (ie, it's not guaranteed to work), sorry for that.  See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin) for a more thorough explanation and an albeit nonportable workaround.  But your workaround works too, +1

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to

`scanf(" %c", &location);`

include a space before the  `%c` for it to ignore the white space or new line.