# While input is not a number, goes into Infinite loop

Tags: c

I'm just a beginner and am trying to make a a program that asks for a number and if a letter is input, it says "that's not a number" and asks for a number again, until a number is input.

However, my program keeps going into an infinite loop with the current code. Any help would be appreciated to fix this. Also, I would also like the program to say "please input something" if nothing is input, but don't know how to do this. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i;
    printf("enter a number");
    while(scanf("%f", &i) != 1)
    {
        puts("That is not a number.");
        scanf("%f", &i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the bad input from stdin after your scanf fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i;
    char trash[1024];

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if (1 == scanf("%f", &i))
          break;

        /* scanf failed: clear the bad input from stdin */

        if (NULL == fgets(trash, sizeof(trash), stdin))  /* NOTE: assumes 1 entry per line and no line longer than 1023 characters */
          exit((fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected EOF or error!\n"), 1));

        puts("That is not a number.");
    }

    printf("You entered: %f!\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

As an alternative to the fgets() to clear the line, you could call scanf("%1023s", trash), which would only suck in the next whitespace delimited series of characters.  This would allow you to handle multiple entries on a single line with mistakes intermixed, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your program goes into infinite loop because after the invalid input, `(scanf("%d", &i) != 1)`condition being TRUE, the *invalid* input which is left in the input buffer is not consumed, it's still in the buffer. So the *same* invalid input is read over and over again.

To avoid, once `scanf()` fails, you need to flush out *all* the input buffer contains before calling next `scanf()`.

Maybe inside the while loop, calling [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) until a newline or EOF will help. Also, the second `scanf()` can be removed, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

After your non numeric[More precisely input which doesn't match the formating of scanf()] input you need to clear the stdin.  If not the same input will be read till stdin get cleaned or you terminate the program. A reference answer can be found on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin)

[Quoted](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Reason for infinite loop : Since you don't clear stdin, same values will be read by scanf() and always full fill while condition resulting in a infinite loop.

Use following edited code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float i;
    char c;

    printf("enter a number");
    while(scanf("%f", &i) != 1)
    {
        puts("That is not a number.");
        scanf("%f", &i);
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // Flush stdin
    }
}
```

Comment: @grammer  Welcome :) you can always upvote/mark correct  what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taking input of a number. Thats why if you even give input a letter, it will take the ASCII value of the letter, which is a valid number. And Further more please take a character as an input. Here I have modified your code which should work

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char i;
printf("enter a number");
while(1)
{
    scanf("%c",&i);
    if (c >=48 && c <= 57) // here ascii value of numbers between 0-9 is 48-57 respectively
   { 
puts("That is a number.");
break;
}
else
{
puts("That is not a number.");
scanf("%c",&i);
}

}
}
```