# File Handling Error in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I am learning file handling in C.I have this code but it is not accepting string as an input to write it to a file.Any help will be appreciated.

```
  #include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        FILE * fp1;
        fp1 = fopen("abc.txt","a+");
        if(fp1==NULL)
        {printf("An error occurred");
        }
        printf("Delete file?\n");


        int a,c;
        char name [20];
        int flag=1;
        int ch=1;
        while(flag!=0)
            {

                printf("Enter id input \n");

                scanf("%d",&a);
                fprintf(fp1,"\n%d\t",a);

                printf("Enter Name");
                gets(name);
                fputs(name, fp1);
                printf("Enter No \n");

        scanf("%d",&c);
        fprintf(fp1,"\t%d\t",c);



        printf("Write more then press 0 else 1");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch==1)
            {
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        fclose(fp1);

    }
```

On running this code the code does not take an input after Enter Name and directly skips to Enter No.I want the output to be in a tabular form.

Comment: You should exit the program when `fp` is `NULL`. Also, indent your code properly so that it is easier for (other) humans to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a number for `scanf("%d",&a);`, you type in a number and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The `scanf` consumes the number and leaves the newline character (`'\n'`) in the standard input stream (`stdin`). When the execution of the program reaches `gets(name);`, `gets` sees the newline character and consumes it, storing it in `name`.

Firstly, never use `gets` [as it is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) as it doesn't prevent [buffer overflows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Use [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) instead:

```
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
```

Secondly, you have to get rid of the newline character. You can do this by [flushing the `stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187514/3049655). Or you can simply scan and discard the newline character just after reading the number from `scanf` by changing

```
scanf("%d",&a);
```

to

```
scanf("%d%*c",&a);
```

`%*c` scans and discards a character.

Answer (score 2):

Use a getchar() after entering id because the \n of 1st scanf stays in buffer.

```
printf("Enter id input \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
getchar();
```

Answer (score 0):

`gets()` is deprecated, don't use it. you can still use `scanf()`...
as for the tabulation...think it through.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("abc.txt", "a+");

    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("An error occurred");
    }

    int a, c;
    char name [20];
    int flag = 1;
    int ch = 1;

    while (flag != 0) {

        printf("Enter id input:\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        fprintf(fp1, "%d\t", a);

        printf("Enter Name:\n");
        scanf("%s", name);
        fprintf(fp1, "%s\t", name);

        printf("Enter No:\n");
        scanf("%d", &c);
        fprintf(fp1, "%d\n", c);

        printf("Again (0) or Exit(1) ?:\n");
        scanf("%d", &ch);

        if (ch == 1) {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);

    return 0;
}
```