# Crash while working with files and linked lists

Tags: c, file, linked-list

I'm writing a program that takes info from a file and adds it to a linked list then and a function that adds info to the linked list. My problem is that when I call `addContact()` after `openBook()` the program crashes, but calling each of them separately works fine.

I can't find the problem.

`openBook()` : opens a file, reads data from file to a linkedList
`addContact()` : takes info, saves data to linkedList

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    char name[50];
    char email[50];
    char ad[200];
    char phone[11];
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

NODE *head = NULL;

void openBook()
{
    FILE *read = fopen("Book.txt", "r");

    if (read == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    NODE *ite = NULL;
    char name[50] = "", email[50] = "", ad[200] = "", phone[11] = "";

    if (!feof(read))
    {
        head = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        fscanf(read, "%s%s%s%s", head->name, head->email, head->ad, head->phone);
    }
    ite = head;
    while (!feof(read))
    {
        ite->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        ite = ite->next;
        fscanf(read, "%s%s%s%s", ite->name, ite->email, ite->ad, ite->phone);
    }
    ite->next = NULL;
    fclose(read);
}

void addContact()
{
    NODE *ite = head;
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        while (ite->next!=NULL)
            ite = ite->next;
        ite->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
        ite = ite->next;
    }
    else
    {
        head = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));
        ite = head;
    }
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter name (no space): ");
    scanf("%s", ite->name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter email : ");
    scanf("%s", ite->email);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter address : ");
    scanf("%s", ite->ad);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter phone : ");
    scanf("%s", ite->phone);
    fflush(stdin);
    ite->next = NULL;
}

void printList()
{
    NODE *iterator;
    int i;
    iterator = head;
    while (iterator != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", iterator->name);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    openBook();
    addContact();
    printList();
    return 0;
}
```

It's amazing the following works :

```
int main()
{
    addContact();
    printList();
    return 0;
}
```

but the following crashes :

```
int main()
{
    FILE *read = fopen("Book.txt", "r");
    fclose(read);
    addContact();
    printList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5958455)

Comment: [Don't do `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187474/5958455)

Comment: [Why `while(!feof())` is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/5958455)

Comment: Your bug is most likely the fact that you may not be setting `head->next` to `NULL` upon creation. Also, listen to this guy^; **edit**: Nevermind, you are.

Comment: @MohamadAliBaydoun No, it's well-formed.

Comment: Did it. Unfortunately, it did't work.

Comment: Where's your `stdlib.h`? You should have received a warning from your compiler for a declaration for `malloc()`.

Comment: I copied the full code and added the missing header. Then it works fine. How?

Comment: Eric Lippert's article about [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) may be worth reading.

Comment: You may want to provide us your input and the content of `Book.txt`. I really can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: `ite->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));` should be `ite->next = malloc(sizeof(NODE));`

Comment: why does the function: `printList()` have the local/unused variable `i`?

Comment: for flexibility, etc it is best to separate the definition of a struct from a typedef for the struct

Comment: the word: `read` is the name of a well known function in C.  It is best to not use function names for variable names.

Comment: regarding: `if (read == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }`  needs some changes.  For instance, there should be a error message to `stderr` and since `fopen()` is a system function, should also output to `stderr` the reason the system thinks the function failed.  Suggest: `if( ! read ) { perror( "fopen for reading 'Book.txt' failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `if(!feof(read))` will not do what your expecting.  Similar considerations exist for `while (!feof(read))`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc, strdup) 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*`.  It can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug,. etc.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `"%s"` or `%[...]` input format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  This is because a NUL byte will always be appended to the input buffer.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. I.E: 11, 50, 200.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement of `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding this statement: `fflush( stdin );`  The function: `fflush()` is ONLY for output streams, not input streams.  Per the C standard, using it on an input stream is undefined behavior.  (even though visual studio allows it)  Suggest using a loop similar to: `int ch;  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );`

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `head = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));`  This is only allocating enough room for a pointer.  What is needed is to allocate enough room for a complete 'NODE'.  Suggest: `head = malloc( sizeof NODE );  if( !head ) { perror( "malloc failed" );  // cleanup all/any prior allocated memory by passing the pointers to `free();` then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", ite->ad);`   Most addresses have spaces, so this will not work.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf( "%199[^\n]", ite->ad ) ) { fprintf( stderr, "trying to input the address failed\n");  // pass all/any prior memory allocations to `free(); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to the answers given above, one more change worth noting is `ite->next = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE*));` which should be `ite->next = malloc(sizeof(NODE));`
You have just done malloc for the size of the pointer `NODE*` but you need to malloc for the size of the `NODE`

Comment: I think that's it (although using `malloc()` with cast and without the proper includes is another good candidate)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are 3 points that are worth noting:

- [Don't cast `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5958455)
- [Don't `fflush()` input streams](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2187474/5958455)
- [Don't use `!feof()` for loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/5958455)

And it seems you're missing `#include <stdlib.h>`. You should have received a warning from your compiler for missing declaration for `malloc()`.

After fixing the missing header, I can't reproduce your problem. I created a `Book.txt` and the program works perfectly fine.

This is my `Books.txt` for testing.

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa
aaa aaa aaa aaa
```

My input used for testing:

```
aaa aaa aaa aaa
```

Comment: @mohammadmozafari Yes.

Comment: What should i use instead of !feof()?

Comment: @mohammadmozafari Use the return value from `fscanf()`. It reports how many items are successfully read.

Comment: worth elaborating: not having a proper declaration of `malloc()` available, and not using proper compiler options, means the compiler will assume it has the old, obsolete default of taking no arguments and returning an `int`, so extremely wrong things will happen when it's called in any other sense, and crashing is no surprise.