# How to read characters from stdin into an array in c?

Tags: c, gcc, stdin, fflush

I last did C in 1991 and now I'm helping a friend with homework.

He has to get characters from stdin into an array.  Seems simple enough.  I figured I'd use [this question as a reference point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin).

We have this:

```
    printf("Input the line\n");
    i=read(0, arg, sizeof(char)*9);
```

IIUC that gets us the characters and based on the answer comment we should be able to put the characters directly into the arg array like this:

```
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF  && i2<9 ) {
     arg[i2] = c;
     i2++;
   }
```

However that prints this [(repl.it link)](https://repl.it/@OleErsoy/devin):

```
 ./main
Input the line
123 456 789

893 456
```

So it looks like even though I'm trying to limit it to indices [0,8] by adding `i2<9` in the while loop, it still grabs `89` and puts it at the beginning of the array since the array only fits 9 characters.

Why is this?  And am I going about this the right way?

We are not allowed to use fpurge.  I assume the professor is trying to teach them how to do this manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do here,

```
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF  && i2<9 ) {
     arg[i2] = c;
     i2++;
   }
```

The above loop is mainly used to consume the left over input in the input stream after `read`.

---

That is, with

```
i=read(0, arg, sizeof(char)*9);
```

You are reading `9` chars into `arg` but you entered `11` chars along with `\n`.

Thus `arg` will have contents,

```
  123 456 (null)   <---contents
  01234567 8       <---indexes
```

remember still `89\n` is left in the stream. thus with `while` loop you are reading `89` into `arg` array from index `0`.

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand it that well either :)

Comment: @Ole Are you clear now? I will try to put more effort in explaining if needed.

Comment: Ok - Got it - good explanation.  I think we are trying to do this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clearing-the-input-buffer-in-cc/