# Gets/fgets jumped over steps of input in C

Tags: c, loops, input, fgets, gets

I have an exercise that I need to create a program to input all information of students as a student report as the source code below. I have a problem that I can't get a full stream input. It stepped over grade input and jumped to another student to input the next student's ID. I have put `getchar()` to get `\n` but it does not help. My problem is in the case 1 of the switch, so you just need to care only about it, the other cases do not make any sense in my question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000
typedef struct 
{
    char id[10];
    char name[50];
    float grade;
    char assess;
}student;
char assess(int a)
{
    if(a<4.00)
    return 'F';
    if(4.00<=a<6.00)
    return 'D';
    if(6.00<=a<7.00)
    return 'C';
    if(7.00<=a<8.50)
    return 'B';
    if(8.50<=a<10.00)
    return 'A';
}
int main()
{
    int choice;
    int i=0, num=0; 
    int a=0, j=0;
    student std[MAX], temp;
    char search[50];
    do
    {
        printf("Student Report\n");
        printf("1.Input data\n2.Append data\n3.Sort data and print\n4.Search by names5.Quit\n");
        printf("Your choice is: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
      {
            case 1:
            {
                do{
                printf("How many students you want to add?\n");
                scanf("%d", &num);
                if(num<0 || num>50)
                printf("Your number must be positive or smaller than or equal to 50!\n");
                }while(num<0||num>50);
                for(i=a; i<num; i++)
                {
                    printf("Student's id No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].id, 10, stdin);
                    getchar();
                    printf("Student's name No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].name, 50, stdin);
                    getchar();
                    printf("Student's grade No.%d:", i);
                    scanf("%f", &std[i].grade);
                    std[i].assess=assess(std[i].grade);
                }
                a=num;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                do
        {
          printf("How many students you want to append?[0; %d]\n", MAX-num);
          scanf("%d", &num);
                }while(num<0||num>50-a);
                for(i=a; i<num+a; i++)
                {
                    printf("Student's id No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].id, MAX, stdin);
                    getchar();
                    printf("Student's name No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].name, MAX, stdin);
                    getchar();
                    printf("Student's grade No.%d:", i);
                    do
            {
              scanf("%f", &std[i].grade);
              if(std[i].grade<0||std[i].grade>10)
            printf("Please re-input grade, it must be between 0 and 10\n");
                    }while(std[i].grade<0||std[i].grade>10);
                    std[i].assess=assess(std[i].grade);
                }
                a=num+a;
            }
            case 3: 
            {
                for(i=0; i<a; i++)
                for(j=0; j<a; j++)
                {
                    if(std[i].grade<std[j].grade)
                    {
                        temp=std[i];
                        std[i]=std[j];
                        std[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
                printf("ID\tName\t\t\tGrade\t\tAssessment\n");
                for(i=0; i<a; i++)
                printf("%-10s%-50s%-10.2f%-10c\n", std[i].id, std[i].name, std[i].grade, std[i].assess);
            }
            case 4:
            {
                printf("Student's name who you want to search: ");
                fgets(search, MAX, stdin);
                getchar();
                for(i=0; i<a; i++)
                if(strcasecmp(search, std[i].name)==0)
                printf("%-10s%-50s%-10.2f%-10c\n", std[i].id, std[i].name, std[i].grade, std[i].assess);
            }
            case 5:
            break;
            default:
            {
                printf("Please reinsert your choice again\n");
                break;
        }
      }
    }while(choice!=5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to mix `scanf()` and `fgets()`; consider sticking with `fgets()` and using `sscanf()` when needed to parse the lines obtained through `fgets()`.

Comment: I think you also have missing `break` statements in your `1` thru `4` `case` blocks!

Comment: @exnihilo I still don't catch your idea to solve my question. Can you explain it more details and post it as your answer instead of comments?

Comment: @AdrianMole I've got your ideas. I corrected it

Comment: 10 is impossible??

Comment: Please when asking a question make sure to include just a [mre], a minimal but complete example of the code that still repeats the problem. "Please ignore this" does not make it minimal.

Comment: You can debug this and print the *stdin to check what's in the buffer - and then write code to free the buffer likewise?

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from `\n` not being consumed by `scanf` at first. To overcome the case I have added `while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`.

To get rid of `\n` character after `fgets`'s usages, I'd prefer to use [strcspn](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcspn&sektion=3).

```
case 1:
{
    do{
    printf("How many students you want to add?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    if(num<0 || num>50)
    printf("Your number must be positive or smaller than or equal to 50!\n");
    }while(num<0||num>50);

    for(i=a; i<num; i++)
    {
        printf("Student's id No.%d:", i);
        fgets(std[i].id, 10, stdin);
        std[i].id[strcspn(std[i].id, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Student's name No.%d:", i);
        fgets(std[i].name, 50, stdin);
        std[i].name[strcspn(std[i].name, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("Student's grade No.%d:", i);
        scanf("%f", &std[i].grade);
        std[i].assess=assess(std[i].grade);
    }
    a=num;
    break;
}
```

Moreover, `asses` function can be simplified as the following.

```
char assess(double a)
{
    if(a < 4.00)
        return 'F';
    if(a < 6.00)
        return 'D';
    if(a < 7.00)
        return 'C';
    if(a < 8.50)
        return 'B';
    if(a < 10.00)
        return 'A';
    else
        return -1; // the error indicator to be handled.
}
```

Further, after each `case`, you should put `break` statements. Glance at [switch](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-switch-case-statement) usage.

Comment: I've edited my program according to your description but my gcc declared error. Is there anything wrong with your program and do you have another way?

Comment: You are using `a` as a `float` but declare it as an `int`. (You also have a no-return-value error, so need to add an `else` or other error-handling return value.)

Comment: @AdrianMole I didn't give attention, but if-elses. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: My gcc show that:
input.c: In function ‘main’:
input.c:52:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcspn’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      std[strcspn(std, "\n")] = 0;
                  ^~~
In file included from input.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:272:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘student * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 extern size_t strcspn (const char *__s, const char *__reject)
               ^~~~~~~
(continue)

Comment: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘student {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘int’
      std[strcspn(std, "\n")] = 0;
                              ^
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcspn’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      std[strcspn(std, "\n")] = 0;
                  ^~~
In file included from input.c:2:0:
/usr/include/string.h:272:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘student * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
 extern size_t strcspn (const char *__s, const char *__reject)
               ^~~~~~~
(continue)

Comment: input.c:55:30: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘student {aka struct <anonymous>}’ from type ‘int’
      std[strcspn(std, "\n")] = 0;

Comment: Actually @snr you should check your source first, this is very long error

Comment: @HoangNam fixed. Did you check?

Comment: @snr ok I've checked it and corrected my source code according to your description but I still get that error. I don't know why. Have you ever made an attempt to run this source code?

Comment: @HoangNam yes, I run. Check the new version.

Comment: @snr I corrected my source code like your newest update. It's ok in the first loop to enter the information of the first student but it's still wrong for the next student

Comment: @HoangNam you can find the solution of  the issue from now on.  I think you should get what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendation I found here - [I am not able to flush stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187474/i-am-not-able-to-flush-stdin)

We can use the below snippet to get rid of the junk in the buffer.

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Now the question is - where to put it in your program?

Well, I put it in the for loop and got the program to run and read all the three params - viz. ID, name, grade; for several entries of students.

Please check the below modified snippet from your program.

```
                for(i=a; i<num; i++)
                {
                    int c; // line 1 added
                    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // line 2 added
                    printf("Student's id No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].id, 10, stdin);
                    printf("Student's name No.%d:", i);
                    fgets(std[i].name, 50, stdin);
                    printf("Student's grade No.%d:", i);
                    scanf("%f", &std[i].grade);
                    std[i].assess=assess(std[i].grade);
                }
```

Comment: if you try this, please compile the program using -std=c99.