# limited input from user in struct

Tags: c, function, input, scanf, fflush

help please this doesnt work properly

input
omayma.firstname : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
omayma.lastname : BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
output : 
omayma.firstname : AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB
omayma.lastname : BBBBBBBBBB
expected output : 
omayma.firstname : AAAAA (10 A exatcly)
omayma.lastname : BBBBBB (10)

```
typedef struct
{
    char firstname[10];
    char lastname[10];
} person;

int main()
{
    person omayma;
    printf("firstname : ");
    scanf("%10s", omayma.firstname);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("lastname : ");
    scanf("%10s", omayma.lastname);
    fflush(stdin);
    puts(omayma.firstname);
    puts(omayma.lastname);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%10s", omayma.firstname);` -> `scanf("%9s", omayma.firstname);`, to save 1 character for `'\0'`. Also, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, it probably won't do what you want it to do.

Comment: Note that a ***lot*** of names are longer than nine or ten characters. (And not everyone has two names.)

Comment: What do you mean, it isn't working properly? What is the expected output?

Comment: thank  u so much that worked. i use fflush(stdin) to empty buffer i cant always use while(getchar()!='\n') because not always the  buffer is full and it will demand from the user to enter a character

Comment: @OmaymaBenali you should account for `EOF` as well. So I would do `for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';);` Or perhaps a bit cleaner, `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");`. But yeah, the buffer being empty issue is always there with these cases.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Pretty sure that `scanf` won't work as expected if the name is shorter than 10 characters. The first conversion will fail, so the second conversion won't be performed, leaving the newline in the buffer.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Sorry, but you can't use `"%*[^\n]%*c"` and "clean" in the same sentence.

Comment: @user3386109 you're right, it will be bad if the buffer isn't actually still full.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 If you find yourself using `%[^\n]` to fix some `scanf`-using code, what you've actually done is proved that `scanf` is, in fact, useless.  `scanf`'s *only* virtue is that it's quick'n'easy for newbies to use.  But if you have to use `%[]`, it ain't quick'n'easy any more, and you might as well abandon `scanf` entirely and use something better.

Comment: @OmaymaBenali Just so you know: `fflush(stdin)` is wrong.  It got you past your problem today, so that's fine, but pretty soon, you'll want to stop using it -- and also stop using `scanf`, too.  (If you don't call `scanf`, you will never need `fflush(stdin)`.)

Comment: what can i use other than scanf or gets which is worse ?

Comment: @SteveSummit yeah, that's fair enough. I find `fscanf` more useful for file parsing, but I agree that user input and parsing do not mix as well. Though I think that no standard method of string input can avoid characters remaining in the stream if there isn't enough buffer space. Which is why a big issue with OP's code is that the buffer size is too small.

Comment: You can use `fgets()` with a nice big buffer and copy a name of the right length into your array. If people want to fool around and enter a silly name that is longer than the nice big buffer, who cares whether the program truncates that and uses what's left for the next input.  Don't use `gets()`. The `gets()` isn't worse: [it is dead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: @OmaymaBenali see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537) for alternatives to `scanf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions to get your code to work as you probably expected it to.

First, provide more space for names.  space is cheap.  Go big (enough)  in struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
} person;
```

Second, if you have to use `scanf()`, make the follow on adjustments for larger buffers...

```
scanf("%49s", omayma.firstname);// adds room for long names,
```

Or, you can get rid of `scanf()` altogether with what may be a better alternative:

```
fgets(omayma.firstname, sizeof omayma.firstname, stdin);
omayma.firstname[strcspn(omayma.firstname, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
fgets(omayma.lastname, sizeof omayma.lastname, stdin);
omayma.lastname[strcspn(omayma.lastname, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline

printf("%s %s", omayma.lastname, omayma.lastname);
```

Third, [fflush()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187514/645128) is only used for output streams:

```
fflush(stdin);//delete this statement (everywhere)
```

Comment: `fgets()` **is** a better alterntive - UV.  Yet reading into the `.firstname` and then lopping of the potential `'\n'` does not nicely  allow to read a _line_ with a first name of 49 characters, just up to 48.  Unfortunately C does not provide a simple alternative.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Thanks for those thoughts.  _Proper_ name length  on this site is a common enough topic. But how often does [someone with a truly long name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff_Sr.) actually need to enter all of it into a hard coded buffer?

Comment: Whatever the save imit (48, 49, 50, ...., 666, ...) I tend to code for an input buffer 2x to consume the entire line and nicely alert if trimmed input exceeds the target.  For line input more than 2x, kinda along [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67810605/limited-input-from-user-in-struct/67810999?noredirect=1#comment119859225_67810605) comment, input is hostile and deserves a more severe response.