# Printing text too often?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

i am new to c and have used python before. This whole buffer overflow stuff is really breaking my mind.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char str1[3];
    while(true){
        scanf("%2s", str1);
        printf("test\n");
    }
}
```

This is a little code i've written to test the syntax and the stdio library. I was really suprised when the program outputted "test" multiple times, depending on how many characters i entered. So for example, when I entered two characters, it printed "test" two times. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your posted code fails to compile on my compiler, because it is missing `#include <stdbool.h>`, which is required if you want to use `bool` in C. Are you using a C or a C++ compiler?

Comment: It's the same thing when I use  1 instead of trrue. I'm using g++.

Comment: What do you mean by "entered 2 characters"?  What exactly was the data on the input stream? Did you try outputting what `scanf` assigned to `str1`?

Comment: I removed the c++ tag on the question, but now I am not sure whether this was appropriate, since you are now stating that you are using a C++ compiler. Why are you using a C++ compiler for compiling C-style code?

Comment: If you are entering data interactively and type `ab<enter>`, I would expect it to print once and immediately block. If you type `a<space>b<enter>`, I would expect the behavior you describe.

Comment: In your question, you wrote: "So for example, when I entered two characters, it printed "test" two times." -- I am unable to reproduce this. Did you enter both characters on the same line? Please specify the exact input, including when you pressed the ENTER key.

Comment: Why need to use `%2s` as the format. Instead use `%s`. Or a better function to be used would be `fgets`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I entered all characters in the same line. It printed test times every two characters i entered, so for example my input character is f:
f test
ffff
test
test
ffffff
test
test
test

Comment: @user15589641 Why would you expect any different?  The scanf only consumes 2 characters at a time, since you specified `%2s`.  As soon as it reads 2 characters, it returns.

Comment: @WilliamPursell but how does that effect the printf?

Comment: If your goal is to learn `C`, stop looking at `scanf`.  It is a completely unnecessary function whose only purpose is to confuse people.  It has no actual purpose.  Time spent learning the foibles of `scanf` is a complete wasted.  Just avoid it.

Comment: Every time scanf returns, a `printf` will be executed and you will see "test" in the output.

Comment: But shouldn't the while loop continue from the top again. I would expect the loop to start from the top after every print of "test" because it is the end of the loop. So no mattre how many characters I enter into the scan function, it will always print "test" once

Comment: What would you recommend to use instead of scanf?`

Comment: If you type `abcdef` into the terminal, scanf will read `ab` and return.  The "test" is printed.  Then it goes to the top of the loop and scanf reads `cd`.    It won't block again until it has exhausted all the available data.

Comment: Now I get it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out what happens by modifying your code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char str1[3];
    while( 1 ){
        scanf("%2s", str1);
        printf("test: %s\n", str1);
    }
}
```

which simply prints the contents of the `str1` alongside of the "test" string.
Here is an example output for an input string of `1234567`:

```
1234567
test: 12
test: 34
test: 56
test: 7
```

The `scanf("%2s", str1);` statement reads two characters from the `stdin` and assings them to the `str1`. The read characters are "popped" from the input stream, i.e., they are removed. If the `stdin` happens to contain more characters, the excess ones are left untouched. Therefore, for the given input, when the first `scanf` is returned, the `str1` containes `12\0`, and the `stdin` contains `34567`.

Since these are in the infinite loop, the code repeats, `scanf` gets called again, reading the first two characters from the `stdin` again, only this time finds `34`.

And the process repeats, untill there are no characters left on the `stdin`, then the `scanf` waits for the user input, presumably as you would have expected.

Basically, `scanf` keeps reading instead of waiting for user input, since the `stdin` already contains something to read.

> So for example, when I entered two characters, it printed "test" two times.

This on the other hand, does not make sense, as it should be printing "test" for N/2 times, rounded up, where N is the number of characters you enter.

---

There is not much that I can suggest for "fixing this", since it is not really clear what you are expecting. But if you want to get rid of the remaining characters in the `stdin`, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your input buffer [as per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2187514/5436259)

Otherwise, you'll read from the stdin, print it, jump back to the loop head and continue reading, if there is still something in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the loop, `scanf("%2s", str1)` reads at most 2 non-whitespace characters from the input stream.  If there are more than 2 non-whitespace characters available in the stream, the loop will continuously call `scanf` (and `printf`) until `scanf` blocks waiting for data.  If the input stream contains `ffff\n` and has not yet been closed (eg, a user is entering data interactively from a tty), the first 2 calls to `scanf` will immediately return and `printf` will be called twice.  The 3rd call to scanf will block until more data is available, or the stream is closed, or there is an error.