# Keep prompting a user for a float if the input to scanf is invalid in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to keep prompting a user for a float, until they enter a valid value.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

  float num;

  printf("Enter a float value: ");
  int success = scanf("%f", &num);

  while(!success) {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter a float value: ");
    success = scanf("%f", &num);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I thought it was an issue with the stdin buffer so I tried flushing that. The weird thing is, `fflush(stdin)` works on macOS but not on linux.

On mac it will keep prompting a user for a float, but on linux it will get stuck in a loop, forever printing "Enter a float value: ". I have also tried `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` instead of `fflush(stdin)` and I get the same outcome.

My question is, how do I keep prompting a user for a valid float until they enter it?

Comment: [fflush(stdin) may invoke undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384073/how-can-one-flush-input-stream-in-c/1384089#1384089).

Comment: @JASLPdoesn'tsupporttheIES Not only *might*. The C specification explicitly say that passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` *is* undefined behavior.

Comment: @Juan The common recommendation is really to forget that `scanf` actually exists. Instead use [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) in combination with `sscanf`.

Comment: Also note that `scanf` (and all other functions in the `scanf` family) can return `EOF`, which is equal to `-1` which is considered "true" when used as a boolean. So with your current code, if there's an error you will have an infinite loop no matter what.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree, but IIRC, I've heard somewhere that Microsoft defines its behavior.

Comment: @JASLPdoesn'tsupporttheIES Yes MSVC add it as an *extension* to the language. Such extension are non-standard and non-portable, and should really not be relied on (which is why I ask compilers to never add extensions, but follow the standards as closely as possible).

Comment: When `scanf(%f", ...)` reads something that cannot be converted to a floating-point number, it will try to read the same data on subsequent scans. Instead of flushing the input stream, you can skip a "word" with    `scanf("%*s")` before re-scanning. (But take the advice above to use `fgets`, which works better with interactive input.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, sounds like as mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude ```scanf()``` is not the right function for this, and ```fgets``` and ```sscanf``` should be used - i'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here, as you've spotted, is that `scanf` doesn't discard invalid input it doesn't consume. Therefore, the solution is to simply process it yourself.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void discard_line (void) {
  int c;
  do
    c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
}

int main (void) {
  float num;
  int rv;
  do {
    fputs("Enter a float value: ", stdout);
    rv = scanf("%f", &num);
    // discard the rest of the line, even if the input is valid
    // you might want to handle valid inputs differently
    discard_line();
  } while (!rv);
  // do whatever you want with the number
  return 0;
}
```

That `discard_line` function I wrote will simply consume all input until a newline (or EOF) is found. (Note that your code doesn't handle EOF at all, so you'll want to do that eventually. Consider adding a check at the beginning of the loop in `main`.) That way, your invalid input will be gone from the `stdin` buffer and `scanf` will read the next line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading any input with `scanf()` and you want to require the user to enter a valid `float` (and within any set value range), you want to loop continually until the user provide valid input. But, understand that canceling input with a manual `EOF` is also a valid user-action, so you should check for and handle that case is a graceful manner.

Another convenience is to provide a way the user can provide a character string as a prompt to be displayed, or none if `NULL` is passed instead of a character string.

A fairly straight forward approach would be something like:

```c
/* read float value from stdin, optionally displaying 'prompt'.
 * on success the value at the address of 'n' is updated with the
 * float input, stdin is emptied and 1 is returned. Otherwise,
 * if the user cancels input with a manual EOF (ctrl + d, or on
 * windows ctrl + z) the value at 'n' is 0 and 0 is returned.
 */
int read_float_input (float *n, const char *prompt)
{
    *n = 0.;            /* (optional) set value at n to zero */

    for (;;) {          /* loop continually until good input or EOF */
        int rtn;        /* variable to hold scanf return */
        float tmp;      /* temporary float value to fill */

        if (prompt != NULL) /* display prompt if provided */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);

        rtn = scanf ("%f", &tmp);   /* attempt read, save return */

        /* validate scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle user canceled input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input).\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        if (rtn == 1) {     /* good input, set *n = tmp, clean, return */
            *n = tmp;
            break;
        }
        /* handle matching-failure (input not an int) */
        fputs ("error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);
        empty_stdin();      /* remove chars causing failure */
    }

    empty_stdin();    /* tidy up to ready stdin for next input */
    return 1;
}
```

If you wanted to specify a range of values, you could add a `min` and `max` parameter and then adjust your check for good input, e.g.

```c
        /* good input with range-check, set *n = tmp, clean, return */
        if (rtn == 1) {
          if (tmp < min || max < tmp) { /* handle out-of-range */
            fputs ("error: value out-of-range.\n", stderr);
            continue;
          }
          *n = tmp;
          break;
        }
```

You also need a way to empty any invalid characters from `stdin` (or your file stream) in the event of a *matching failure*, like if the user slips typing `456.89` and types `r56.89`. In that case, a matching failure would occur when `'r'` was encountered, character extraction from the stream would cease leaving `"r56.89"` in your input buffer unread. To extract the offending character, you just read and discard characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered. You can do that with something like the following (or just read using `fgets()` and perform the conversion using `sscanf()`), e.g.

```c
/* if a matching-failure occurs while using scanf(), character
 * extraction from stdin ceases with the first offending chararacter
 * leaving the offending character(s) unread (likely leading to
 * an infinite loop if calling scanf() in a loop). To empty stdin
 * you must repeatedly read characters until '\n' or EOF is encountered.
 */
static void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();              /* read char from stdin */

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)   /* repeat until '\n' or EOF */
        c = getchar();
}
```

A short example putting the pieces together could be:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/* if a matching-failure occurs while using scanf(), character
 * extraction from stdin ceases with the first offending chararacter
 * leaving the offending character(s) unread (likely leading to
 * an infinite loop if calling scanf() in a loop). To empty stdin
 * you must repeatedly read characters until '\n' or EOF is encountered.
 */
static void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();              /* read char from stdin */

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)   /* repeat until '\n' or EOF */
        c = getchar();
}

/* read float value from stdin, optionally displaying 'prompt'.
 * on success the value at the address of 'n' is updated with the
 * float input, stdin is emptied and 1 is returned. Otherwise,
 * if the user cancels input with a manual EOF (ctrl + d, or on
 * windows ctrl + z) the value at 'n' is 0 and 0 is returned.
 */
int read_float_input (float *n, const char *prompt)
{
    *n = 0.;            /* (optional) set value at n to zero */

    for (;;) {          /* loop continually until good input or EOF */
        int rtn;        /* variable to hold scanf return */
        float tmp;      /* temporary float value to fill */

        if (prompt != NULL) /* display prompt if provided */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);

        rtn = scanf ("%f", &tmp);   /* attempt read, save return */

        /* validate scanf return */
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle user canceled input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input).\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        if (rtn == 1) {     /* good input, set *n = tmp, clean, return */
            *n = tmp;
            break;
        }
        /* handle matching-failure (input not an int) */
        fputs ("error: invalid float input.\n", stderr);
        empty_stdin();      /* remove chars causing failure */
    }

    empty_stdin();    /* tidy up to ready stdin for next input */
    return 1;
}

int main (void) {
  
  float f;
  
  if (!read_float_input (&f, "\nenter float: ")) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  printf ("\nvalid float value: %f\n", f);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

With matching failures handled prior to good input:

```
$ ./bin/valid_float

enter float: float
error: invalid float input.

enter float: r56.89
error: invalid float input.

enter float: 456.89

valid float value: 456.890015
```

Or with user canceling by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl + z</kbd> on windows) with an error code of `1` returned to the shell:

```
$ ./bin/valid_float

enter float: (user canceled input).
$ echo $?
1
```