# How can I handle user input for a double array in C, allowing both int and float values while ensuring they fall within specified constraints?

Tags: c, input, types

Question is to take elements of a (2D) array from the user, but the elements can be of either int or float datatype. These are the following constraints:

> Element Values:
>
> Integers: -2147483648 to 2147483647 (range of int in C)
> Single-precision floating-point numbers: -3.402823e+38 to 3.402823e+38 (range of float in C)

When the user inputs a number that is out of range, the program should stop execution.

## What I tried:

- make the datatype of array be double
- if user inputs int, check if it's int and check for constraints (& similarly for float)

```
double a[n][n];

printf("Enter Elements (Row-wise):\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]) != 1)
        {
            printf("-1");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Check range constraints

        if ((int)a[i][j] < INT_MIN || (int)a[i][j] > INT_MAX)
        {
            printf("-1");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (a[i][j] < -3.402823e+38 || a[i][j] > 3.402823e+38)
        {
            printf("-1");
            exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

## What the issue is:

Even if I attempt to input values as large as 2183812748347, the compiler only returns 2183812748347.0

2183812748347 clearly exceeds the max limit for int, and I think it still considers it as a float.

How do I fix this issue?? Or, is there a better way (that is still beginner friendly)?

Comment: Don't cast to `int` when doing the comparison.

Comment: The first thing you need to think about is what happens if the user types in "Fred" as an input?

Comment: *"-2147483648 to 2147483647 (range of int in C)"* That's not necessarily true. The only requirement is that int have a range of at least -32767 to 32767. You won't see many machines where it's that small anymore, but you might see -(2^64-1) to 2^64-1 occasionally. The code does it *partly* right, though: INT_MIN and INT_MAX are the things to use. But when you do `n < INT_MIN`, and `n` is an int...that can never be true, because an int *can't* be less than INT_MIN.

Comment: @dcp Shouldn't the `if (scanf("%lf", &a[i][j]) != 1)` part handle that?

Comment: You say "elements can be of either int or float datatype", but yours are neither.  I think you need to expand a bit on the actual requirements.

Comment: @Min Archie This if statement if ((int)a[i][j] < INT_MIN || (int)a[i][j] > INT_MAX) does not make sense because an object of the type int can not be less than INT_MIN or greater than INT_MAX.:)

Comment: @001 - As with most things in C, depends on the hardware and implementation (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313967/keep-prompting-a-user-for-a-float-if-the-input-to-scanf-is-invalid-in-c)

Comment: If you need to apply different range constraints depending on the form of the input then you need to *see* the form of the input.  Your approach does not support that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `(int)a[i][j]` when it exceeds the valid `int` range? Just skip those casts.

Comment: @dcp I don't see the relevance of your linked question since, in this post, they `exit(1)` on bad input.

Comment: Aside: don't hard code the floating point ranges: use `FLT_MAX` and `-FLT_MAX` etc.

Comment: @001 - Yes, that's fair.  What OP has may be ok (as far as reading the input) in this case.

Comment: @Min Archie First of all declare the array with the type specifier float. I can suggest the following approach. Read numbers in a character array. Then try to apply standard function strtol. If it fails then try to apply standard function strtof.

Answer (score 2):

OP's code has troubles:

**Never true**

`(int)a[i][j] < INT_MIN` is never true (expect when UB occurs some place) as an `int` is never less than `INT_MIN`.
To properly test if a floating point object can convert to an `int`, do the compare as the floating point type.

```
// Assume INT_MAX is a power-of-2 minus 1.
#define FLT_INT_MAX_PLUS1 ((INT_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0f)
if (fp >= FLT_INT_MAX_PLUS1) too_high();

// Assume INT_MIN is a - power-of-2.
// Instead of out-of-range INT_MIN - 1
// else if (fp <= INT_MIN - 1) too_low();
// use
else if (fp - INT_MIN <= -1) too_low();

else i = (int) fp;
```

**Wrong limit**

`+/- 3.402823e+38` is near `FLT_MAX`, yet its exact value is certainly the slightly larger `3402823_46638528859811704183484516925440.0f`.

**Inexact**

When input is not exactly encodable as a `float`, OP is not clear on how to handle.  This affects edge conditions with `FLT_MAX` and rounding of values near a whole number.

Reading in text as a `double` and then converting to a `float` may incur [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding) rounding errors.  Better to convert once to a `float`.

---

Instead, use `strto...()` to assess as below.  `(f)scanf()` and friends are UB when input is outside the specifier range.

Read the line of user input as a string and then parse it twice, as a `float` and `int32_t`.  All 4 combinations are possible depending on criteria used.

Even if the below is not exactly as OP's desire's, use a helper function to parse the input.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// Length of the widest exact float
#define FLT_STR_N (FLT_MANT_DIG - FLT_MIN_EXP + 3)

// Read a line of user input.
// Return 0: neither float nor int32
// Return 1: int
// Return 2: float
// Return 3: both
// Return EOF on end-of-file, input error.
int input_float_or_int(float *f, long *i) {
  // Let us use 2x max output size to handle inputs with lots of spaces and leading zeros, ...
  // No reason to be too conservative here.
  char buf[FLT_STR_N * 2 + 1];

  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    return EOF;
  }

  int retval = 0;
  errno = 0;
  char *endptr;
  long lvalue = strtol(buf, &endptr, 0);
  if (endptr > buf && errno == 0 && lvalue >= INT32_MIN && lvalue <= INT32_MAX
      && *endptr == '\n') {
    *i = lvalue;
    retval |= 1;
  }

  errno = 0;
  float fvalue = strtof(buf, &endptr);
  if (endptr > buf && errno == 0 && *endptr == '\n') {
    *f = fvalue;
    retval |= 2;
  }

  return retval;
}
```

There are numerous details not handled here including:

- Input longer than `buf[]`.
- Should a decimal point `'.'` ( or maybe `','`) deny conversion to an integer?  E.g. Should `2147483647.0` convert *exactly* to an `int32_t` or round to the nearest `float` (2147483648.0), or both?
- Are additional or zero trailing white-space allowed?  What should happen with input like `123zxc`?

Comment: I think your gyrations with `FLT_INT_MAX_PLUS1` are some attempt to avoid `INT_MAX` not being representable in `float`. But OP’s code uses `double` for getting the data and predicates that upon `double` being able to represent all `int` values. So merely comparing their `double` value with `INT_MAX` suffices; `INT_MAX` will be converted to `double` without error. If we want to eliminate the assumption `double` can represent every `int` value, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51107035/298225).

Comment: However, if are reading as a string and then determining whether the input matches an `int` or `double` or neither, then `strtol` can be used, since it reports range errors, after which the `long` it returns can be compared directly to `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As reading user input as `double`, and then converting to `float`, may incur _double_ rounding, this answer strives to 1) avoid that 2) not assume `double` precision exceeds `int32_t` even if `double` commonly does.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I read OP's question, the end goal is not `double` vs. `int`, but  `float` vs. `int` (and assuming `int` is at least 32-bit.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil "... then strtol can be used," and that is what is done in the sample code.  What does remain TBD is cases like  "2147483647.0" or "214748364.7e1".  OP has not detailed that corner.  Likely OP want to jump to `float` upon seeing a `'.'`, even when saving as an `int` affords greater precision.